# What is the difference between iRST Raid 1 and Intel Rapid Recover Technology?

Tags: motherboard, intel-rst

What is the difference between iRST Raid 1 and Intel Rapid Recover Technology ?

Intel wrotes: " It uses RAID 1 (mirroring) functionality to copy data from a designated master drive to a designated recovery drive"

http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/technologies/000005652.html

But what it adds to RAID 1?

It can be used with different type of drives?
Both drives are viewed from Internet Explorer but recovery drive is read only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RAID1 requires all drives in the mirror be online and working at all times, and appear as a single volume/device to the OS. If one drive goes offline, the volume is still available to the OS, but the RAID array is considered "degraded".

With RAID1, during normal operations both drives are accessed for both reads and writes, are kept in sync on the fly, and there is no master/salve relationship.

Intel Rapid Recover Technology will use "RAID1" technologies to mirror the master drive to the slave (aka "recovery drive"), but once it's done syncing, the "RAID1" it was using ceases to exist.  this way the slave drive can be removed from the system, and/or accessed as separate (read-only) volume.

As is shown here in the explanation from your link:

> •Continuous: Changes made to data on the master drive while the system
>   is not docked are automatically copied to the recovery drive when the
>   system is re-docked.

So RAID1 is for redundancy and performance increases, and IRRT is for system recovery (more similar to Previous Versions, and Restore Points, within Windows itself).

[More info from Intel](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/rapid-storage-technology.html)

> It can be used with different type of drives?

Yes, but like regular RAID1, the (recovery) volume will be the size of the smaller drive.

Comment: Thank you. But generally "degraded" RAID is perfectly accessible for all operations. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degraded_mode  Is it an iRST specific? or RAID1 specific? or iRST RAID1 ?

Comment: It seems I got it. Am I right: after "undocking" of recovery drive and then "docking again" RAID 1 will require full copy from master drive to recovery when using RRT system will "use restore points" to syncronise disks and there will be only changes applied on "recovery drives"?...

Comment: "But generally "degraded" RAID is perfectly accessible for all operations", sure but it's not considered to be in a stable state. From the system's POV there is something wrong with the RAID volume when in degraded mode (hence the name), IRRT doesn't report as degraded wen the one drive goes offline.  "Is it an iRST specific? or RAID1 specific? or iRST RAID1 ? "  Is _what_ iRST specific?

Comment: "It seems I got it. Am I right:"  Basically, yeah.  Specifically you shouldn't/can't "undock" a drive from a RAID1 and have it still appear as stable. IRRT doesn't have that problem, because it terminates the RAID1 relationship once it's done updating the recovery drive.  The trade off is that IRRT doesn't perform redundancy if the master dies, the computer goes down), and you lose out on speed increases that RAID achieves by performing simultaneous actions on more than one drive at a time.

Comment: Thank you. May be you know scenario when temporal "undock" of recovery drive can be useful?  It seems it is not for desktop systems. And more concrete question to clarify iRST RAID1 specific: if my system volume is iRST RAID 1 and it become degraded (one drive broken) am I able to launch computer and continue to work for some time?

Comment: It seems like RRT could be useful for time to time backuping system drives... But I have never heard about external PCI slots...